# Android app can't post to url

Tags: android

I'm working on a relatively simple login app for a school project. I'm having an issue connecting my app to any URL, local or otherwise. I've added the permission for internet access to the android manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The following code is located in my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText  username=null;
    private EditText  password=null;
    private Button login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ucidText);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passText);
        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


//URL CAN BE ANYTHING, WOULD NORMALLY BE 192.168.1.102
        if(isConnectedToServer("<-URL to page on locally hosted server->",10)){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


//Function to determine if connection exists
    public boolean isConnectedToServer(String url, int timeout) {
        try{
            URL myUrl = new URL(url);    //<--------- I believe the issue has to do with this line. 
            URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
            connection.connect();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {         
            return false;
        }
    }   
}
```

This is a stripped down version of my overall project. Everything checks out except the connectivity. I'm running the app from the SDK straight on my phone (Moto X). Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Do you get any errors? If so, what are they?

Comment: `catch (Exception e) {         
            return false;
        }` This is probably a VERY BAD IDEA. If any problem occurs, you simply ignore many details that an exception can give you to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: The URL object won't function unless I include the throws declaration. A e.printStackTrace() returns

    **java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found "URL"**

Does this mean I have to specify an http protocol?

Comment: What is the **exact** URL you provide? Note that it must be well-formed. This means you must supply **some** protocol, such as "http" (but it can be any valid protocol...you don't provide enough information for us to make any suggestions).

Comment: Previously, my url was just the IP address of my server
`192.168.1.102/cstest/index.php`
When I change it to 
`http://192.168.1.102/cstest/index.php`
The app crashes and I get the following in [LogCat](http://pastebin.com/Kgns7emt).

I'm sorry if I don't provide all the info at once, I'm new to Android and still learning, so I don't know what to look for initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the  android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException because you perform your network request on the main thread. You should not do that because you will block the main thread. Instead, you can start a new  thread to perform your network request, like this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
new Thread(){
     public void run(){
       // check network connection here.
       handler.post(/* do the toast work in a Runnable as the parameter here*/);
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: @Phreakradio It's right, AsyncTask can also solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should use some protocol in the "url" string.

For example, you can use

```
 "http://serverIP"
```

in which the serverIP is 192.168.1.102 and the port is default to 80.

We could not use "192.168.1.102" as the url because the protocol could not be ignored for the URL class.

Comment: When I add the `http://`, the app crashes and the following comes up in the [LogCat](http://pastebin.com/Kgns7emt).